# Magento 2 : How to override fotorama.js in magento custom theme , to add one image at the end of the gallery

Tags: magento2

I need to add one image (the same image) at the end of the gallery images for all products, in file **fotorama.js**. How can i do that? I know there are other ways to do that , but it is **important** that I do that with **fotorama.js** (preference or plugin)
Does anyone knows that how to solve it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution after some R & D on `fotorama.js` I override the file of `fotorama.js` in My_Theme.

```
app/design/frontend/[My]/[Theme]/web/fotorama/fotorama.js
```

I want to Enable both gallery nav arrow and don't want to hide nav arrow when slider goes up and down in vertical way arrow. Also i want to enable that arrow only if image is more than 4.

Lets see in fotorama.js for enabling both arrow.

> line no 22.

```
//wrapToggleArrowsClass = wrapClass + '--toggle-arrows',
  wrapToggleArrowsClass = wrapClass + '',
line no 33.

//arrDisabledClass = arrClass + '--disabled',

  arrDisabledClass = arrClass + '',
From Line no 2635 to 2664

function arrsUpdate() {
            /* var disablePrev = disableDirrection(0),
                disableNext = disableDirrection(1);
            $arrPrev
                .toggleClass(arrDisabledClass, disablePrev)
                .attr(disableAttr(disablePrev, false));
            $arrNext
                .toggleClass(arrDisabledClass, disableNext)
                .attr(disableAttr(disableNext, false));
        */}

        function thumbArrUpdate() {
            /*var isLeftDisable = false,
                isRightDisable = false;
            if (opts.navtype === 'thumbs' && !opts.loop) {
                (activeIndex == 0) ? isLeftDisable = true : isLeftDisable = false;
                (activeIndex == opts.data.length - 1) ? isRightDisable = true : isRightDisable = false;
            }
            if (opts.navtype === 'slides') {
                var pos = readPosition($navShaft, opts.navdir);
                pos >= navShaftTouchTail.max ? isLeftDisable = true : isLeftDisable = false;
                pos <= navShaftTouchTail.min ? isRightDisable = true : isRightDisable = false;
            }
            $thumbArrLeft
                .toggleClass(arrDisabledClass, isLeftDisable)
                .attr(disableAttr(isLeftDisable, true));
            $thumbArrRight
                .toggleClass(arrDisabledClass, isRightDisable)
                .attr(disableAttr(isRightDisable, true));
        */}
```

Comment out these two functions, after this your gallery arrow will not hide.

For the enabling nav arrow when image is more than 4.

```
"navarrows": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */  echo (($block->getVar("gallery/navarrows") == 'true') && ($block->getGalleryImages()->count() > 4)) ? 'true' : 'false'; ?>,
```

Arrow enable is more than 4 answer source. display arrow if image count is greater than 4

Now every thing is as per requirement.

Hope it helps!!